# path algebra and quiver

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, monoid, quiver

Im studyng quivers with the text of Assem:[image]

My question is: In "the words on {$\alpha, \beta$}", refers it in particular to the free monoide kleene star? I dont uderstand the relation with the free monoid.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the set of all words on $\{\alpha, \beta\}$ is the free monoid over $\{\alpha, \beta\}$, usually denoted $\{\alpha, \beta\}^*$.